# Error installing PHP using Web Platform Installer on Windows 10/IIS 10

Tags: php, asp.net, windows, iis-8, web-platform-installer

I am trying to install `PHP 7.1.1` on Windows 10, `IIS 10`, using Web Platform Installer 5.0.

I am getting an error:

> PHP 7.1.1 (x64) The product did not install successfully

> Windows Cache Extention and PHP manager for IIS fail too, but I believe it is because of dependency on PHP 7.1.1.

I have already tried these:

1. set this key value to 8:

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services/W3SVC/Parameters/MajorVersi
2. .Net 3.5 installed and WCF TTP Activation is enabled for .Net Framework 3.

What's the best way to get the PHP files working on my machine?

Comment: Not much of  PHP person so a different approach: What does the plugin do that you can't do in ASP.Net? Or some `Nuget` package? Is it some core functionality that you have to spin off (and ultimately manage) a PHP app on the server? If it is, then I'd ask myself why _"I'm developing an ASP MVC site"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up [installing PHP manually](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-install-php-on-windows/). Web Platform Installer has many problems with PHP installation, and manual installation of PHP was fairly simple.

Comment: You should accept this, and maybe add a link to the manual steps like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-a-php-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-php#13-download-and-install-php-manually